# AWS S3 bucket access for role/users- Select Role Type

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My intention is simple- to create a role that I can assign to a standard user of my AWS account so that they can read/write to one of my S3 buckets.

I've created a policy to apply to the role and I'm happy with that bit.

The thing I'm a bit confused about is the "Select Role type" screen in the management console (see attached image). I can't work out what I'm supposed to choose at this stage as none of the descriptions seem to apply to the simple thing I'm trying to achieve. 
Does anyone have any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you are on the wrong path here. Roles are not ACLs for users, but for systems and services.

See: [IAM Roles](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles.html)

If you want to grant a user access to some AWS resources you should have a look at the policy section. Either use a pre-build (like `AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess` or `AmazonS3FullAccess`) or define a policy on your own.

You can then assign this policy to a user. If you want to manage multiple users this way, you can also use groups to assign policies to users.

Comment: Ok,  maybe i'm barking up the wrong tree, here is what the requester has suggested "We'll need two roles, one that read/writes on the one bucket, one on the other. We can have *one* user, that will assume a different role every times it is running for test or for prod."